# Connecting a bathroom fan/light combo?

Tags: wiring, bathroom, exhaust-fan

I'm replacing my old bathroom fan with a new fan/light combo. The new fan/light has four(4) wires, but the existing switch has only three(3) wires. How do I wire this set-up? There are white, blue, and black wires on the fan/light, and what I guess is a screw for the ground wire. But the existing switch wires are white, black, and a bare copper wire. I really want the fan and light to come on with a single switch if possible. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

Tie the black and blue wires to the incoming black wire, the white wire to the incoming white wire, and the bare wire to the ground screw.  This will allow you to turn the fan and light on and off as a unit.